# How is the spoiler tag used? (not working in one topic)

Tags: support

I'm trying to use the spoiler tag here

[Why is Trunks not as powerful as Gohan when they are both human-Saiyan hybrids?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34246/why-is-trunks-not-as-powerful-as-gohan-when-they-are-both-humans-saiyans-hybrid/37179#37179)

like this..

```
<spoiler>
Spoiler's content
</spoiler>
```

but it doesnt work. How is it used?

Comment: For additional information on how to format Stack Exchange posts using our flavor of markdown, see: http://anime.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Answer (score 4):

You can add a spoiler tag using `>!`

> spoiler tagged using >!

as opposed to the normal >

> normal text using >

I also added the spoiler tag in the answer mentioned for you.

Comment: I wanted to know as well. Plus 1, great explanation.

Comment: is this still working? It doesnt seem to be working anymore .